# Rails passthrough to other application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-core

I am building a rails website that must pass some routes through to other applications (written in ASP.Net Core). The rails website must serve some pages define as normal rails views/controllers, and some that come through from the other ASP.Net applications.

Authentication will only be handled at the Rails level.

This means that some rails controllers will call the other applications (which are not publicly accessible) by sending all post data through and send back their response directly without parsing or further looking at it.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Configuring web server (nginx, apache) seems to be the best way to do it.  Nginx should decide which application (rails or other) is responsible for handling certain url

Comment: Does not seem viable, since *authenitication will only be handled at the rails level*. We want to use the same devise authentication for all three applications (Rails, ASP.Net A, ASP.Net B).